# Django Python Shell Query All Objects Issue with Decimal

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am storing auction items and my app runs successfully in the browser-meaning all the auction items I have created are displaying with the correct start and end dates.  And those start and end dates are being stored as `DateTimeFields`, and what is being stored is a datetime object using `datetime.now()` which does includes the microseconds.  As in:

```
2020-01-20 14:06:22.398123
```

In the python console, I run the following:

```
from auctionitem.models import AuctionItem

AuctionItems.objects.all()
```

I get a nasty error about an invalid decimal operation:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Sir Chris Mazzochi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 252, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "C:\Users\Sir Chris Mazzochi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 258, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Sir Chris Mazzochi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\Sir Chris Mazzochi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 74, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "C:\Users\Sir Chris Mazzochi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1081, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, connection)
  File "C:\Users\Sir Chris Mazzochi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\operations.py", line 286, in converter
    return create_decimal(value).quantize(quantize_value, context=expression.output_field.context)
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
```

model.py (for AuctionItem)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
import datetime
print("Running for Mazzo")

class AuctionItem(models.Model):

    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='auction_items')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    startBid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    buyNowPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    buyNowEnabled = models.BooleanField()
    deliveryCost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    now_no_micro = now.replace(microsecond=0)
    startDate = models.DateTimeField(default=now_no_micro)
    tdelta = datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    enDate = now_no_micro + tdelta
    endDate =models.DateTimeField(default=enDate)
    viewCount=models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

    def incrementViewCount(self):
        print('Hi Chris Mazzochi')
        self.viewCount = self.viewCount + 1
        self.save()
```

I'm wondering if the decimal this error is referring to is the one in that datetime object with the microseconds appended with a 'dot', '.', ...is this here where my error is? Do I need to store the date sans the microseconds?

Thanks,
Ironman

Comment: What do you get for `AuctionItems.objects.all()[0]` and have you altered the `__str__` function for your `AuctionItems` model?

Comment: @n1rna thanks for responding.  When I run objects.all()[0] I get <AuctionItem: Test Item 1>, and I have updated my question to reflect the model.

Comment: Then I guess you have a decimal validation problem in the `title` of one of your records. Try printing them one-by-one. For example, `[0]` of your list seems to be fine.

Comment: @n1rna is right. Just clean the table, or Download https://sqlitebrowser.org/ SQLite browser and see, which row is the issue by the opening database.

Comment: Actually I fixed it.  I did what my current solution reflects.  I simply removed the microseconds part of the datetime before storing it.  And now objects.all() returns my auction items. Thanks all for weighing in...